# Set fixed label size for grouped bar chart in angular Chartjs

Tags: angular, charts, angular-material, chart.js, bar-chart

i am new at angular and chartjs, i have my bar chart code as:

```
const chart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Success Prediction Count',
      data: dataCases.successCount,
      backgroundColor: '#ffbb33',
      borderColor: '#ffbb33',
      fill: false,
      // borderWidth: 30,
      maxBarThickness: 50,

    },
    {
      label: 'Failed Prediction Count',
      data: dataCases.failedCount,
      backgroundColor: '#ff4444',
      borderColor: '#ff4444',
      fill: false,
      // borderWidth: 30,
      maxBarThickness: 50,
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    title: {
      display: true,
      text: 'Training Model Success And Failed Prediction Count Chart'
    },
    tooltips: {
      mode: 'index',
      intersect: false
    },
    hover: {
      mode: 'nearest',
      intersect: false
    },
  }
});
```

and my bar chart as:

[image]

here I have 77 labels which look very small and it's proportional to the label count. if I have a label count of 10 the label size increases and the  chart looks like this:

[image]

I want to give the labels a fixed size so that labels size doesn't change regardless of the label count, could you please help me out on this, I have tried all the chartjs options but couldn't find any solution. thanks in advance :)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you read [Labelling Axes](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/labelling.html) and [Tick Configuration?](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/scale-options/ticks.html)

Changing the [tick font size](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html), changes the tick size, but also the amount of ticks. Here is a fiddle to show the effect: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/2yzwLkvd/8/)

```
scales: {
    xAxis: {
        type: 'time',
        ticks: {
            font: {
                size: 15,
                padding: 5,
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: thanks for the help. i can set the size of labels as fixed size now but now the problem is the labels are not proportional with the bars , for example in my case when i increase the labels font size , each label has morethan 2 bar but i want to also increase the size of bars proportional with label size so that each label will belong only for 2 bars like above second picture.

Comment: @AshrafYawar It seems like your project would really benefit from a zoom plugin, to allow you to read the chart easily, but still keep the proportions right.  [More on plugins.](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/plugins.html)  [Where to find plugins.](https://www.npmjs.com/search?q=chartjs-plugin-)  [The zoom plugin i use.](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chartjs-plugin-zoom) [Also some documentation on it.](https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-zoom/)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, do you think there are other alternatives? i have dig into the charts documentation but couldn't find any solution for this issue, i have tried to make use of padding but it only works for chart padding not the label padding.

Comment: @AshrafYawar You have so much data i really don't see an alternative. In the first picture you are already squeezing the data in there, so to make the bars and ticks bigger there would really have to be no padding anywhere. And i couldn't find any more padding for you to set to 0.